# Is Windows's CRITICAL_SECTION prevent other thread to be executed

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to check if it's really the case : when a particular thread is inside a critical section, the others threads of the program which are not in the critical section are prevented from execution ?

I posted this question because some people think that mutex are better than critical section, because this last may block the other thread that are not using the critical section.

take a look at this URL : http://www.careerride.com/VC++-critical-section-mutex-and-semaphore.aspx it this true ?

Comment: Other threads cannot enter the same CRITICAL_SECTION at the same time. They do not stop executing other code or entering other CRITICAL_SECTIONs

Comment: If properly used, a critical section will block other threads if they try to enter the critical section while a thread in already in that section. So you can have only one thread executing the code between entering and exiting the critical section. The OS will switch to another thread that is not blocked.

Comment: In the 17:09 UTC edit, the careerride link is either misleading or very poorly worded. The result is the same, and I have to call it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, not all the threads are blocked.
Only those threads all blocked, which wants to enter the same critical section.

Your question is that you want to check working of threads.

My explanation will be focused around using Visual Studio IDE as you have asked about Windows critical section.

Have a global variable int loop = 1;
Have critical section which only has code while(loop); (infinite loop)

Have at least 2 threads in the program. Run the code in debugger.
See the threads view in the IDE and you will see that one thread is just stuck at while(loop).

Just freeze that thread and toggle to another thread. Just run the other thread, and you will see that it will not move further and it will just keep on trying to enter critical section.

Now change the value of loop to 0 from watch view of debugger.
And still nothing will change as the first thread thats holding critical section was freezed. Now just put the break point on line while(loop) and run the freezed thread, then you will see that because we have changed the value of loop to 0, the thread that was holding the critical section will exit the critical section.

And wow the other thread will stop at the break point and it has now entered the critical section.

So to expand the scope, add 3 thread in your program which does not use critical section.

Run the program and you will find that the above holds true only for the threads having critical section but the third thread which does not use critical section just ran and finished without any issue.

Answer (score 2):

Let me try to make it simple.

You are driving on a road, and then you see a RED signal. You have to stop till other do use the crossing. Your waiting has no connection to any other road in city, country or entire world.

If a signal in London is green or red, and you are waiting on San Francisco's particular signal - it really doesn't matter if that signal on London turns green (you won't be allowed to pass through). Neither the London's signal being red prevents you from not crossing the signal.

Similarly, none of such signals would prevent any of vehicles on express highway. The other vehicles are not blocked by the signal you are waiting on (they are free threads in OS perspective).

Assume set of all vehicles on particular signal is a thread. Then on a four crossing signal, there would be three threads waiting for signal to turn green. Only one thread (set of vehicles) can proceed further (utilize the road), all other 3 (or more) threads must wait.

This is what CS and mutexes are for. If you are blocked with `EnterCriticalSection` or `WaitForSingleObject`, you are waiting for that signal light to turn green for you (the waiting thread).

Answer (score 0):

In the general sense, no. Other threads carry on unaffected unless they attempt to enter a region protected by the same CRITICAL_SECTION. Those threads may be blocked until the critical section becomes available, depending on how you try to enter and when.

The first to enter the critical section has no problems, but once a thread enters, no other thread may enter until the critical section is left.

A thread, "B", trying to enter a critical section occupied by "A" will block until "A" exits the critical section unless "B" first tests that they are permitted to enter, for example with [TryEnterCriticalSection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms686857(v=vs.85).aspx), and elects to do something else rather than wait.

[I recommend giving this a read.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms682530(v=vs.85).aspx)

I also recommend, if C++ 11 or a more recent standard is an option, using the [`<thread>` library's](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) mutual exclusion facilities to improve your portability.